# Using class selector for autocomplete, need to get associated element id

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I have implemented Dylan Verheul's Autocomplete 1.6 JQuery plugin on a web page.  I am using the autocomplete on 20+ different input boxes on the page.  A class name is being used as the selector.  The autocomplete works fine on each of the different input elements, though I am having trouble getting the ID of the current input element we are on.

Basically the HTML is this:

```
<form name="myform" action="blah.asp" method="post">
  <input class="ItemMatchText" type="text" id="selectQuestion_104657" name="selectQuestion_104657" value="">
  <input class="ItemMatchText" type="text" id="selectQuestion_104664" name="selectQuestion_104664" value="">
  <input class="ItemMatchText" type="text" id="selectQuestion_104710" name="selectQuestion_104710" value="">
</form>
```

The JavaScript is basically like this:

```
$(function() { 
  var selectedId = "";
  $('.ItemMatchText').autocompleteArray(ItemArray, {
    autoFill:true,
    matchContains:true,
    onItemSelect: function(data1) {
      selectedId = data1.extra[0];
      }
  });

//...
});
```

The line: selectedId = data1.extra[0]; gets the next column in the array for the selected row.  In this same event, or any other for that matter, I would like to get the element Id that is currently being typed in to evoke this autoselect.

Everything I have tried either returns the LI element or the first INPUT element on the page with the class, ItemMatchText.

How do I get the input's ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
onItemSelect: function (data1) {
    selectedId = $(data1).attr('id');
}
```

Try that (I'm not terribly familiar with this plugin but after reviewing the source this should be it).

Comment: I thought so too, but data1 is an LI element.  Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not implemented.

You could try create separate autocmpleters for every input:

```
$(function() {  

$('.ItemMatchText')
.each(
        function()
        {
          $(this).autocompleteArray(ItemArray, 
            {
              autoFill:true,
              inputObj:this,
              matchContains:true,
              onItemSelect: function() 
                            {
                              alert(this.inputObj.id);
                            }
            });
        }
      );
});
```

Comment: it runs through the items stored in $('.ItemMatchText') and adds the autocompleteArray-ability to each one . By this you can have separate settings for every single input(instead of actually unique settings for all inputs). I added one setting  there, **inputObj:this**, a pointer to the related input-element.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the autocomplete script a couple of times I decided I had to be able to return the input value given to the function in the first place.

Here is the beginning of the function:

```
jQuery.autocomplete = function(input, options) {
    // Create a link to self
    var     me = this;

    // Version
    var     version = 1.6;

    // Create jQuery object for input element
    var     $input = $(input).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Based on its usage I assumed input was the input:textbox element selected.  I than searched the code for onItemSelect and found:

```
if (options.onItemSelect) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        options.onItemSelect(li)
        }, 1);
}
```

To expose the input variable with the LI element I simply added it:

```
if (options.onItemSelect) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        options.onItemSelect(li, input)
        }, 1);
}
```

I could then simply grab the input element on the onItemSelect event.

```
$(function() { 
  var selectedId = "";
  var inputId = "";
  $('.ItemMatchText').autocompleteArray(ItemArray, {
    autoFill:true,
    matchContains:true,
    onItemSelect: function(data1, inputElm) {
      selectedId = data1.extra[0];  // Get the next column of in data row
      inputElm = inId.id;           // Get the input's Id!
      }
  });

//...
});
```

This is probably not the best way to go about this, but it worked for this case.  Of course I need to re-minify the file.